# Why is a Bitmap in memory much larger than image file on disk?

Tags: winforms, bitmap

I have an image file that is 6 mb on disk.

When I load it using

```
Dim nBmp As Bitmap = Bitmap.FromFile(sPath)
```

... TaskManager shows an increase of used RAM of my app of around 200 mb.

I could confirm this because if I do this around 6 times, the RAM goes up to 1,2 GB, and further attempts to do that raise an out-of-memory error.

So it's actually true that so much is being used.
I don't process this bitmap any further.

Why is the bitmap so much larger than the file on the disk?

Comment: Which kind of Image are you loading? When its a compressed file (like jpeg) it will be decompressed loaded into memory...

Comment: @feal It's a PNG.

Comment: @feal You're right, thank you. Can you make your comment the answer? I exported the image as raw data in GIMP, and the file size was 190 mb, so you must be right that 6 mb is the compressed image while 190 mb is the uncompressed data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are loading an compressed image. PNG in your case. The `Bitmap.FromFile` will decompress it and then load it into memory as uncompressed Bitmap. Which needs much more space. As you said in the comment: 6MB as PNG and 190MB as Bitmap.